# missing id passed in urlindent

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I am trying to upload file on server and to view the file uploaded I have to pass the model id to the view action. It is all good untill I add

```
'options' => ['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']
```

to my ActiveForm. After I add it the id passed to the action view by URL doesn't show anymore and I get missing parameter message.
i am using yii 2.0.2

Create action:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new SubContent();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
        //$fileName = $model->id;
        $model->save();
        $fileName = $model->id;

        $files =UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'files');

        $files->saveAs( 'uploads/'.$files->getBaseName().'.'.$files->getExtension());
        $model->files=$files;

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Form:

```
<div class="sub-content-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'files')->fileInput(['maxlength' => 255]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'sub_id')
              ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Subjects::find()
              ->where(['year'=>\Yii::$app->user->identity->year])
              ->all(),'id','sub_name'),
              ['prompt'=>' select subject']
          ) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

and this is my model

```
         <?php

       namespace frontend\models;

       use Yii;

            /**
        * This is the model class for table "sub_content".
           *
         * @property integer $id
        * @property string $files
           * @property integer $sub_id
           *
          * @property Subjects $sub
           */
            class SubContent extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
           {
           /**
            * @inheritdoc
             */
             public static function tableName()
             {
            return 'sub_content';
               }

             public function rules()
            {
               return [
              [['files', 'sub_id'], 'required'],
             [['sub_id'], 'integer'],
           [['files'], 'string', 'max' => 255]


         ];
        }

        public function attributeLabels()
          {
           return [
           'id' => 'ID',
           'files' => 'Files',
            'sub_id' => 'Sub ID',
            ];
             }

           /**
          * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
           */
            public function getSub()
              {
               return $this->hasOne(Subjects::className(), ['id' => 
           'sub_id']);
           }
            }
```

edited..... still didnt work

Comment: on model you change like this
[['files'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true],

Comment: @Umar Ali still not working my friend

Comment: show me your error

Comment: show screenshot of an error

Comment: @UmarAli i had knew what is the wrong,it is from the

Comment: @UmarAli   (<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>) it make an action link ,can i force it to not have any action?

Answer (score 0):

First of all - since 2.0.8 you don't have to add `enctype`, it's done automatically when you add `fileInput` field.

You are **not** verifying if `$model->save()` returned `true` and it looks like that model **did not pass** validation and because of that `$model` is **not saved** and because of that `$model->id` is **not set**.

You should do something like:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new SubContent();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {

        $model->files = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'files');

        if ($model->save()) {
            $model->files->saveAs('uploads/' . $files->getBaseName() . '.' . $files->getExtension());

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

For this to work you need to set proper validation rules in `SubContent` model.

Comment: what should i do after verifying  if  $model->save() returned true

Comment: i gope you can answer me

Comment: ***********hope

Comment: What do you mean? Everything is answered. Check model validation rules and see what is wrong with the data you are posting.

Comment: ,ok i see ,i am not strong Enough in yii2 ,thar is why i am not knowing how to chek model validation ,and I am grateful to you

Comment: Read this [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html) - I hope it will help you.